# How would I diagnose what error seems to lead to non-functional underscore wildcard queries in Postgresql 15?

Tags: postgresql

I am working through a quick refresher ('SQL Handbook' by Flavio Copes), and any LIKE or ILIKE query I use with the underscore wildcard returns no results.

The table is created as such:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    names CHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO people VALUES ('Joe'), ('John'), ('Johanna'), ('Zoe');
```

Given this table, I use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE names LIKE '_oe';
```

I expect it to return

|  | names |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe |
| 2 | Zoe |

Instead, it returns

|  | names |
| --- | --- |

The install is PostgreSQL 15 (x64), pgAdmin 4, and PostGIS v3.3.1

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29

Answer (score 2):

Using char(20) means all strings are exactly 20 chars long, being padded with spaces out to that length.  The spaces make it not match the pattern, as there is nothing in the pattern to accommodate spaces at the end.

If you make the pattern be '_oe%' it would work.  Or better yet, don't use char(20).

Comment: Thank you. What would be the best practice for creating a field wherein the text string may approach (but does not pad to) 20 characters?

Comment: @DarrellCarvalho: `varchar(20)`